# Dev Studio 2013 new MVC project does not have Startup class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have seen a number of posts asking what has happened to Global.asax and what is the Startup class.

I have the opposite question. When I create a new MVC / Web API 2 project (via Web / ASP.NET Web Application / Web API Template) I still get Global.asax as the entry point and not Startup.cs

Just wondering how it is that others have the (Owin) Startup class by default (I do have the option of adding the startup class via Add | New Item | OWIN Startup class)

Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose it depends on what template was used. Do you have any addon templates?  Some sort of error happen?  Latest service pack?

You can add one by Add > Add New >  OWIN Startup Class or you can manually add a class called startup.cs and the owin references, system.web, ect. and it will work.

Comment: Hi William, thanks for that. Yes, I just manually added the start-up class, and use it for my entry point. I just saw some others talking about getting it by default when they created their MVC project (where as I didn't). The posts I saw looked like the people did not add any templates, so I assumed this is a default template that I did not have for some reason. I will be on the look out for such a template though.